# Advanced android app for mapping and GPS logging?

Tags: gps, android, software-recommendations, mapping, oruxmaps

I am looking for an android app able to log GPS data like coordinates, altitude, current speed and would be nice if also the GPS accuracy/number of satellites. Many GPS apps are able to display these data, but not to log them.

Reason is that while doing a monitoring (no matter if helicopter, car or on foot), there is a variable accuracy of the coordinates and so this also influences the measurement results and the output maps. So it would be helpful to know these data to take this into consideration.

I am currently using Oruxmaps, but it logs only date/time, position and elevation and not the other data. Just found [Antimap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trentbrooks.AntiMapLog) and [Geopaparazzi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.hydrologis.geopaparazzi&feature=also_installed) which I will surely try, but I am after other recommendations.

I also need to work in offline mode.

Answer (score 5):

The Best is Sport Tracker (originally developed by Nokia)

[image]

Will log GPS data like coordinates, altitude, colour codes the route with GPS accuracy/number of satellites (optional)

**Exports** to GPX and KML (CSV and XML)
Can view on the map or via Google Earth on Android (Ice Cream Sandwich - Android 4.0.3 works best) for this.

Available on Google Play (App Store for Android now)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stt.android&hl=en

Video showing the features
http://youtu.be/QQUffYt8fRk

Answer (score 2):

Is writing your own app out of the question? Location information is exposed through the LocationManager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

And the data you are likely referring to are in the NMEA string:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html

Comment: Hi, I am not a programmer so writing my own app is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can download gpx data from the Endomondo sport app 
You can do this from the website once the data is uploaded.
Just view the workout and select export in the right hand pane